# Inserir valor no array em uma determinada posição através de uma condicional

Tags: php

tenho o seguinte array:

```
array(143) {
 [0]=>
 string(0) ""
 [1]=>
 string(0) ""
 [2]=>
 string(5) "item1"
 [3]=>
 string(5) "item2"
 [4]=>
 string(5) "item3"
}
```

e minha seguinte lógica para encontrar um valor no array:

```
$abaixo = "item2";
foreach ($arrayName as $key => $value) {
        if (strpos($value, $abaixo)) {
          // aqui ele vai mostrar o "item2", 
          // ou seja, ele ta na posicao do "item2"
        }
}
```

precisava saber um jeito de dar um `array_push()` depois daquela posição encontrada, ou seja, eu to procurando no array o meu `$abaixo` que é `item2` ai ele achou, preciso inserir um valor, embaixo do `item2`

obrigado

**RESPOSTA**

```
    foreach ($arrayName as $key => $value) {
        if (strpos($value, $abaixo)) {
            $posicao = $key + 1;
            array_splice($arrayName, $posicao, 0, $arrayInsert);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Não é mais simples usar `in_array()`, se o valor encontrado em [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) estiver na posição zero vai dar false.

Comment: dá uma olhada aqui: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-unshift.php [add inicio] http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-push.php [add final]
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-pop.php [remove final]
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-shift.php [remove inicio]
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-splice.php [add parse]
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-slice.php [remove parse]
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-merge.php [junta arrays]

Comment: @Furlan Se a sua resposta foi a que você acabou usando, ao invés de colocar no final da pergunta, o melhor é criar uma resposta e marcar como aceita. Não tem problema nenhum fazer isso `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos supor que seu array seja uma coleção assim:

```
$colecao = ['item1','item2','item4','item5'];
```

E você quer inserir um item na chave 2, depois da chave 1 (item2) que faltou chamado "item3", basta fazer isso:

```
array_splice($colecao, 2, 0, "item3");
```

E depois você pode continuar seu `foreach`.

Veja funcionando aqui:
**http://ideone.com/12IPOk**